# How to Count the Number of non-NA's between NA in Vector R

Tags: r, vector, na

You have the following vector which has NA's mixed in. There are no consecutive NA's and the vector is of unknown length. There are always the same number of NA's.

```
#Data
testvector <- c(NA,rnorm(round(abs(rnorm(1))*10)),NA,rnorm(round(abs(rnorm(1))*10)),NA,rnorm(round(abs(rnorm(1))*10)),NA,rnorm(round(abs(rnorm(1))*10)),NA,rnorm(round(abs(rnorm(1))*10)))
```

You need to find the number of non-NA values that exist after each NA. This needs to be return as a vector. The length of this vector will equal the number of NA's.

For this vector.

```
thisvector <- c(NA,rnorm(4),NA,rnorm(5),NA,rnorm(9),NA,rnorm(2),NA,rnorm(6))
```

What you want is

```
somefunction(thisvector)
[1] 4 5 9 2 6
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rle` on the output of `is.na` to get what you want:

```
x <- rle(is.na(testvector))
x$lengths[!x$values]
## [1] 1 2 5 9 4
```